# removing punctuation from the word with function. Language: python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to define a function which will take  one parameter, a string which represents a word, and removes characters considered punctuation from everywhere in the word. I am trying to use the .replace() function only.

For example: if the word is " inc#credi!ble" it will return "incredible". However, the one I am writing now is replacing only one parameter. Below is the code:

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(word):
   for char in word:
       if char in punctuation_chars: 
           char_without_punct = word.replace(char,"",)
   return char_without_punct
```

y = strip_punctuation("#incr!edible")
print(y)

Comment: To make your current approach work, you need some kind of double loop, one over characters, and another over the punctuation list.  But I suggest using regex instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try literally the opposite of what you said. Make a new word of the characters that are *not* punctuation.

```py
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']


def strip_punctuation(word):
    word_without_punctuation = ''
    for char in word:
        if char not in punctuation_chars:
            word_without_punctuation += char
    return word_without_punctuation
```

However, it's better not to build your own bicycle and use `str.isalnum()` function:

```py
def strip_punctuation(word: str) -> str:
    word_without_punctuation: str = ''
    char: str
    for char in word:
        if char.isalnum():
            word_without_punctuation += char
    return word_without_punctuation
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a regex replacement here:

```py
import re

punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
regex = r'(?:' + r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in punctuation_chars]) + r')'

def strip_punctuation(word):
    word = re.sub(regex, '', word)
    return word

inp = "inc#redi!ble"
print(strip_punctuation(inp))  # incredible
```